# How to remove commas from string in database with SQLite in C?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have problem on removing all comma from string data in SQLite database.

The program is based on C so I use C API of SQLite as sqlite3_mprintf().
I try to get rows matched with input and it needs to be checked without comma(,).

REPLACE() of SQLite is used as REPLACE(data, ',', '').

Sample code is below.

```
sqlite3_stmt *main_stmt;
const char* comma = "','";
const char* removeComma = "''"
char *zSQL;
zSQL = sqlite3_mprintf(SELECT * FROM table WHERE (REPLACE(colA||colB, %w, %w) LIKE %%%q%%, comma, removeComma, input);
int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, zSQL, -1, &main_stmt, 0);
```

I refer the sqlite3 reference.
https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html

Any Substitution Types of SQLite3 reference delete apostrophes from input data.
It makes REPLACE() functions different from what I think.

What I expect is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (REPLACE(colA||colB, ',', '') LIKE %q`
by passing **','** and **''** as argument of **sqlite3_mprintf()**.

However, result is changed as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (REPLACE(colA||colB, ,, ) LIKE %q`
so comma is not removed from data, colA||colB, and result is different from what I expect.

Are there any idea to input comma as first argument of REPLACE() with apostrophes
and blank with apostrophes as second argument?

Comment: @xing Thanks for giving me advice. I tried but it is same. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (REPLACE(colA||colB, ,, ) LIKE %input%);` is shown as SQL query.

Comment: @AnonCoward If I change `%w` as `%Q`, there is error **SQL: wrong number of arguments to function REPLACE()**. The SQL I can find by log is same as `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (REPLACE(colA||colB, ,,) LIKE %q`

Comment: @AnonCoward How do you apply it? I only make change %w into %Q above code.